# Venn diagram layout with d3.js

Tags: javascript, position, d3.js, diagram, venn-diagram

Is there a sample on how to do Venn diagram using d3.js? I know about the [two](http://bl.ocks.org/1067636) [samples](http://bl.ocks.org/1067616):

[image]

[image]

that are provided on D3 website. However they force me to calculate by myself the x.y position of the circles. I am hoping to feed just the data (circle sizes and overlap size) to a function/chart and it should do the layout for me.

Comment: I don't think anybody has built a reusable venn diagram chart yet. Are you going to be putting data in the chart (labels or other information), or you literally are just looking for a bunch of overlapping circles?

Comment: I can do without putting data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get an understanding of the required algorithm, read Leland Wilkinson's paper, [Exact and Approximate Area-proportional Circular Venn and Euler Diagrams](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~wilkinson/Publications/venneuler.pdf), published in IEEE TVCG February 2012. To the best of my knowledge no one has yet implemented a `venneuler` layout in D3, but that would make a fantastic [D3 plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins).

Answer (score 12):

[Venn Diagrams with D3.js](http://www.benfrederickson.com/2013/05/09/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js.html)

[image]

[image]

It is working fine.